# how to traverse json api data object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am trying to get the current temperature of a specific location using a weather api. I'd like to use the response of the weather api and store in State using react.

My problem is that i keep getting an error when traversing the json data.

`WeatherApp.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp_c' of undefined`

Here is the json response data i logged to the console.

[image]

**Per request here is the response from weather.current**

[image]

code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function WeatherApp() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getWeather() {
      Axios.get(
        "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=xxxx&q=40507"
      )
        .then(response => {
          setWeather(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log("There was an error that occurred."));
    }
    getWeather();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello!</h1>
      {console.log(weather.current.temp_c)}

      // I am able to print to the console when i do the following
      {console.log(weather.curret)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default WeatherApp;
```

Am I not traversing the json data properly?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log` to your error so you have a better idea. `catch(e => console.log(e));` and share the result here.

Comment: hi, the error is not coming from the api request. the error is coming from `{console.log(weather.current.temp_c)}`

Comment: try outputting ```{console.log(weather.current)}``` in console, see if it's returning any data or returning undefined

Comment: try ```{Object.keys(weather).length > 0 ? console.log(weather.current.temp_c) : ''}```

Comment: @KetanRamteke updated the question to include an image of what you requested. That works fine. However when I do `{console.log(weather.current.temp_c}` i get the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting that your effect is asynchronous.

On the first render, `weather` is going to be set to `[]`, because that's what `useState` is setting it to. You queue up an effect to be completed at a later time but then render the pre-effect elements:

```
return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello!</h1>
      {console.log(weather.current.temp_c)}
    </div>
  );
```

Since `weather` is equal to `[]`, `weather.current` is `undefined`. `undefined.temp_c` is a `TypeError`.

Place your `console.log` in code that runs *after* your data is fetched.

Comment: if that is the case. Why am i able to print to the console when i do `{console.log(weather.current)}` and not get an error?

Comment: Because `[].current` evaluates to `undefined` instead of throwing a TypeError. Accessing any undefined property of an object value returns `undefined`. In contrast, trying to access any property of a `null` or `undefined` value throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: Gotcha thank you. What is the best way to get around this? Should i set a dummy initial state?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. I'm guessing your ultimate goal isn't to console log something. Rather, you'll want to render something for the user that lets them know the data is loading, so you could check if `weather` isn't populated and return something like a spinner instead. Then when the effect completes, your component will re-render with the populated `weather` state.

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `weather`, that you specified, is `[]`: an empty array.

`[].current` will be undefined, hence the error.

Either use a more complete set of default data. or test if `weather.current` has a value.

Comment: Hi `weather.current` does have a value when i print to the console. I only get the error when i do `weather.current.temp_c`